# Why does SWIG fail to parse a template / struct?

Tags: swig

I am trying to wrap a .h file using SWIG with the following really simple interface file:

```
%module example
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "../pointmatcher/PointMatcher.h"
%}

/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "../pointmatcher/PointMatcher.h"
```

The wrapping attempt fails with the following error:

```
C:\Data\Projects\lpm-source\libpointmatcher-swig\wrapper>C:\Data\Downloads\swigw
in-3.0.5\swig.exe -csharp -cpperraswarn example.i
..\pointmatcher\PointMatcher.h(61) : Warning 205: CPP #error ""You need libnabo
version 1.0.6 or greater"".
..\pointmatcher\PointMatcher.h(130) : Error: Syntax error in input(1).
```

The line in question is:

```
template<typename T>
struct PointMatcher  <-- this line
{
```

from this file: https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher/blob/master/pointmatcher/PointMatcher.h#L130

Why is the SWIG parsing failing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swig is parsing the file as a C file instead of C++, and does not understand the `template` keyword. Try:

```
swig -c++ -csharp -cpperraswarn example.i
```

See the [swig documentation on wrapping C++](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nn5).

Also, the function like macros `DEF_REGISTRAR(...)` and `DEF_REGISTRAR_IFACE(...)` will confuse swig. So either `%include` the file where these are defined, or just define them away by adding

```
#define DEF_REGISTRAR_IFACE(...)
#define DEF_REGISTRAR(...)
```

before the `%include "../pointmatcher/PointMatcher.h"`.